# Store all SQL Server column values of a record as unique variables in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm writing a program in C# that will grab data from a staging table, and then insert that same data back into their new respective locations in a SQL Server database. The program will do the following steps sequentially:

1. Select columns from first row of staging table
2. Store each column as unique variable
3. Insert data into new respective locations in the database (each value is going to multiple different tables in the DB, and the values are duplicated between many of the tables)
4. Move to the next Record
5. Repeat from step 1 until all records have been processed

So is there a way to iterate through the entire record set, storing each result from a column as a unique variable without having to write separate queries for each value that you want to store?  There are 51 columns that all have to go somewhere, and I didn't think it would be very efficient to hardcode 51 variables each with a custom query to the database.

I thought about doing this with a multidimensional array, but then that would just be one string with a ton of values. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why write a program for this?  Sql Server Integration Services is intended for this purpose (among others).

Comment: Just a straight SELECT INTO will do this.

Comment: So we can automate the process for end users

Answer (score 2):

Although you can do this through a .NET application, really this would be much easier to achieve with a SQL statement. SQL has good syntax for moving data between tables:

```
INSERT INTO [Destination] ([Columns,])
SELECT [Columns,]
FROM [Source]
```

If you're moving data between databases, you just need to link one of the databases to the other and then run the query. If you're using SQL Server Management Studio, you can follow [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx) to set up linked servers. Otherwise, you can use the [`sp_addlinkedserver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx) procedure to register the linked server.

Comment: Thank you.  I am familiar with INSERT SELECT FROM statements and have used them before.  However in this case we are cleaning up a large database of contact information.  This will be an ongoing process and the idea behind the program will be to automate the task so that our end users can enter new information via a custom intranet portal without having to ask the IT dept. to do a database update every time.

Comment: Is there something that prevents you calling this T-SQL statement from the client application that would otherwise execute your iterative approach?

Comment: No not at all.  I was asked by my boss to do it like that, but now that I think about it that may not be needed.  As long as the loop moves to the next record it shouldn't matter...maybe I approached this the wrong way.

Comment: If your boss can indicate there are some constraints that make this approach unacceptable, add those constraints to your question and you can get some more answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that contains a property for each column in your table and use a micro ORM like Dapper to populate a list of instances of those classes from your database.  You can then iterate over the list and do your inserts to other tables.

You could even create other classes for your individual inserts and use AutoMapper to create instances of those from your source class.

But... this might all be overkill for what you are trying to achieve.